# Specify pointer address space for variables/kernel parameters

Tags: c++, optimization, cuda, memory-address

TL;DR: Is there a way I can tell the compiler that a given pointer will always be a global pointer so that it can omit the unnecessary conversion instructions?

Consider the following example ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIAruiakl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtEywZ7HAGTwNMAHLuAEaYxCAArKQADqgKhHYMLm4eerHxtgK%2B/kEsoeFRVpg2iUIETMQEye6eXJaY1pkMZRUE2YEhYZGW5ZXVqXUKvW1%2BHXldEQCUlqgmxMjsHAD6S8C0qMFiKwDUAG6oeOjbtmwKAEwQfgTbAFRMkwCkGgCCDwDsAEJPrxoAnHe3B4AZgAItszsCvi93iDvhxprROBFeJ4OFpSKhOE45CDntsnA8zl8idsFLN5phtoSgTxSARNPDpgBrSIafScSQohkYzi8BQgNn0tHw0hwWBINAsaJ0MLkSiS6X0cIMXbIZBcLhvUhYXZ4BYANTwmAA7gB5aKMbk0WgEML8iDBbnBPwVACenFpkrYglNDFo7uF2swLEMa0W6PwxGKtl2mH5gcwqmKJlt3KuDW5tDwwWIbpcWG5BGIeBYHpFVAMwAUhpN5st3F4/EEIjE7CkMkEihU6kDujqBiMKDMFizwX5kGmqGiTXjAFoABrT1RMBTbWem9FFEr2CCOfq1Ug%2BUa5fJpOIJAT7s8ZRLtE9dQYNaOlYZXx%2BNF%2BtO%2BdcKDV%2BuGo9CGL9jx/CRpjJOYFnA9kOGRUhUXRTEOG2AJ9ScJxtg1AA6N5sI0bYIFwQgSCpM4aUmXghS0aYICQWYCGiFM5V3fAiGLdA9CbYRRHEdtuK7NRuT7UhjVzaIywRJEuUDZDTRTJjrlQKhUPQzCcLwgiIBcKUZWIMiKKohlaKQHU9UwFiFT0gJWEWNCMKwrhcPw3hMDYkhDi42QWz46QBKUITeyAp9t08XcGGcACBkPCLv3GX9pHSC8kiig8kqaOLT3bLcmhaPpUuCj8BDykYcjA7L/xSA9gMqTKH0kaYi0wTBPI0KS4JkpDOBBTBdQWbYa2NMJVIcjT8MI4j2IMup8VQXSlWmyi6WM5lWVgzlSFLLgNDZRDeGQvkQDOZbhUmdqzk6/beROmjpljYh4nsSQgA)):

```cpp
__global__ void times2(int *a)
{
    *a *= 2;
}
```

With the resulting PTX:

```
.visible .entry times2(int*)(
        .param .u64 times2(int*)_param_0
)
{
    ld.param.u64    %rd1, [times2(int*)_param_0];
    cvta.to.global.u64      %rd2, %rd1;
    ld.global.u32   %r1, [%rd2];
    shl.b32         %r2, %r1, 1;
    st.global.u32   [%rd2], %r2;
    ret;
}
```

But let's say I happen to know that I will only every call this kernel with a global pointer: How do I tell the compiler that it can omit the `cvta.to.global.u64` instruction? The best I could come up with is this: ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIAruiakl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtEywYgATKUcAZPAZMADl3ACNMYhAAdlIAB1QFQjsGFzcPb3jE5IEAoNCWCKjYq0wbFKECJmICNPdPH1LygUrqgjyQ8MiYyyqauozGvvbAzsLu6IBKS1QTYmR2DgBSLwBmQOQ3LABqJdWnBQJ8QQA6BD3sJY0AQSvrgH174FpUMLFH7YA3VDx0bds2AovE8Xm9aPc4gRiBBAgRtgAqJiTO5LaIAIRRGgAnExdqsACLbGGCBGTR7IT5VEGvd5EJ6MSJ4ZBQWGQ4j3AiTJF7DE3K5YxEIvaErw8lHRfEcaa0TgAVl4ng4WlIqE4Tjk%2BOu2ycKwxXjR2wUs3mmF2ax4pAImil0wA1iBZRp9JxJArrSrOLwFCAnValVLSHBYEg0Cw4nRIuRKKHw/QogxPshkFwuLEsJ8mZgAGp4TAAdwA8nFGO6aLQCJFvRAwu6woFqgBPTgW0NsQQFhi0Jv%2B0hYFiGZ6LZX4YhlWyfTDenuYVRlEwV92wzAynu0PBhYiNlxYd1QvAsZsBqgGYAKHP5osl7i8fiCERidhSGSCRQqdQ93RcfQDlBmCxrsJvUgaZUEhFIpwAWgADUhVQmAUbYIILZUmlsewIEcAZPC/fxRgKIo9ASJI0NSVx6kI7ISI6fDui/VCKmGLC9HolphmoroojoxiyIyLi2nY8ZOOmI05gWCRpTlN0e1VDhtmCLMnCcbYUxOaITg0IlcEIEgzVWLhJl4P0tGmCAkFmAg4nnKMMPwIhiF%2BPRb2EURxCfJzXzUd1P1IPNNziQ8JI4eVSEVZUZILedLLhVAqDkhSlJUtSNIgFwwwjYhdP0wzrRMpB00zayY3S4JWEWeTFOUrhVPU3hMFskgHK/Jz71c6R3KUTyP2Y5cxxSBwGGcHjsNWXwBoEgiuCdIiclI9JsKyYiUnG7oADZLB65oGFafohokEaWK2ti8I4iQnUONomL4mplqiFbpihTBMAcjRAuC0LeBk/FMAzBZtnPPNIjiirEvUzT6oylY9NIbVUDSuNMoMy0crtB0nRXV1SAPSanXej0OC9TIjJtZ0OC8KSws9JH/UmaYJ2IJJ7EkIA))

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>

__global__ void times2_global_ptr(int *a)
{
    a = (int *)__cvta_global_to_generic((intptr_t)a);
    *a *= 2;
}
```

The resulting PTX is exactly the same as above, apart from the missing `cvta.to.global.u64` instruction & some renamed registers:

```
ld.param.u64    %rd1, [times2_global_ptr(int*)_param_0];
ld.global.u32   %r1, [%rd1];
shl.b32         %r2, %r1, 1;
st.global.u32   [%rd1], %r2;
ret;
```

Here's an attempt to create a working program using this: ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIAruiakl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtEywZ7HAGTwNMAHLuAEaYxCAATBGkAA6oCoR2DC5uHnpxCbYCvv5BLKHhUZaY1lkMQgRMxAQp7p5cxaVJFVUEOYEhYZHRCpXVtWkNva3teQXdAJSWqCbEyOwcAKQRAMx%2ByG5YANSLK069%2BIIAdAi72IsaAILLawwbZpg7e3a9xJisZxfXVwD6P8C0VDBMR/LYAN1QeHQW1sbAUEQgfgIWwAVEwJl9FgB2ABCmI0AE40ajdgARLYRXZ4q7Y0n4y5/AFAkE/cGQ6GwzDw/6A4G0H4xAjERGCVHozG4/EEphPcki5EoiZ/ZBgyo85n8oj/RhhPDIKBIwXEH4ECbilbU75EmUoskUqkSulXJFbFhMPwQDE0yU0wkulHBExUUiowNUH4IeIEB2%2BgmmcwAWTEgP1ywAbGGQwkAF6YVBUeUTDEWqXxphJ2gpgASUYg6bDEajWbwufzheLlqlAaDjd6svtJdjZYTmBYyBiAE8IJmtg3I71m62C0iplth6PxxPSZgqEwTLRTTHvlbOfDdk5z%2BeGlsuJ8Vud79Ogx2paeIuq%2BQKhZe9leQ7f7zvbAnyoF9fStdcx0nEDewIEMZxzPNl0EVdIM3bdd33Q9BytA4QBQGZkR/JxQx7eciN/PYtjAJYAFYnAYGij1pDgploThaN4TwOC0UhUE4Jw5FJS4tgvCI8XErYFBmOZHhuHhSAITRWKmABrEBaI0fROEkLjlL4zheAUEAtKUnjWNIOBYCQNAWBiOgwnIShbPs%2BhwgYMFkGQLguCxUgsDBPVMAANTwTAAHcAHkYkYfSaAPMJjOnfTgj8KoJ04BTbLYQRIoYWgMvM/zR0MAEFl4/A3hsPAwS5fTMFUTBTAIcreCREp9NoPBgmIdKXCwfShTwFhMosqgDGABRQoi6LYu4Xh%2BEEEQxHYKQZEERQVHUIrdAaAwjBQMwLC64JjMgKZUEFJJjI4ABaAANQVVCYBQtluyLeKsJqygcBhnFcOovD%2B0ZOnCBoMkSAQBnqWJ4khhgQfyLohhKb7mj6GoAcGRo0YEFpqkR8Yhgx6G9GGAm/A6JGwamaTZnmCQ2I4vSiv4jgtgCYKnBInyjixI4NC2CBcEIEgdlWLgJl4MytCmCAkEImITDgigIEwfAiGIKE9EW4RRHENbdc2tR9N20hwt6mJRqZjhONIbjeLZyLlaV5F8w5rmea4PmBaFlw7Ic4hxZWSXpeUuWkACoKnIgFzA4CVgFk57mb29/nePV0WtfQHXZGWg3pCNpQTZ2snUeq%2Bw1b%2B0mGh8SmxmR2HMiSGum/hwnG6%2BivyhJrGYa7sp8baevQbJ3vUn7jGO5pxS3kwbWNBtu2Hd4Nnt0C%2BYtmm8Kwg9lPefToWRc14Pr391zd/kqXFPDtSNK09iOF00gRq4DQtJXgyOCMyIb/MottIcAiCzR2hk/6yymLVYgCR7CSCAA))

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>

__global__ void times2(int *a)
{
    *a *= 2;
}

__global__ void times2_global_ptr(int *a)
{
    a = (int *)__cvta_global_to_generic((intptr_t)a);
    *a *= 2;
}
int main()
{
    int *buf, *buf_host;
    cudaMalloc(&buf, sizeof(int));
    cudaMallocHost(&buf_host, sizeof(int));

    *buf_host = 2;
    cudaMemcpy(buf, buf_host, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDefault);

    times2<<<1, 1>>>(buf);
    times2_global_ptr<<<1, 1>>>(buf);

    cudaMemcpy(buf_host, buf, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDefault);
    std::cout << *buf_host << '\n';
    // Prints 8
}
```

I copy a 2 into device memory and multiply it by 2 using both versions of the `times2` kernel. As expected, the result is 8, so nothing seems to obviously go wrong here.

My questions are now:

- Is `a = (int *)__cvta_global_to_generic((intptr_t)a);` a valid way to force the compiler to omit the conversion instruction? Is there a more direct solution?
- It is my understanding that global pointers are always valid generic points (i.e. they map to themselves when converting). Combined with the fact that `cudaMalloc` allocates global memory, I assume I don't need to convert anything. Is this correct?

Comment: Maybe you should study the SASS instead of the PTX.  You are wasting your time studying the PTX.  PTX is largely unoptimized code.